# Pseudo-elements :before & :after not working in IE 10 or 11

Tags: html, css

In Edge, Google Chrome and Firefox the code works fine but in IE it will only show the after and not the before either side of my heading 2 tag.

### Clear achievable strategy

```
h2 { color: #333333; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; position: relative;
    font-size: 30px; padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;}

h2:before, h2:after { position: absolute;
    top: 51%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 18%;
    height: 1px;
    content: '\a0';
    background-color: #333333; }
h2:before {
    margin-left: -20%;
    text-align: right;
}
h2:after {
    margin-left: 2%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me - it's just your bad positioning (margin-left:-20% on an element that is only 18% wide will mean that it is off screen): https://jsfiddle.net/w4q401vq/

Comment: Maybe IE applies the margin % differently than the other browsers, because in IE11 when I change the `h2:before`'s `margin-left` value from `-20%` to `20%` it shows the before line (though not lined up exactly right).

Comment: Try two colons for pseudo elements. e.g. `h2::before`, instead of `h2:before`. Most browsers play nice, but we're talking about IE, so..
More here: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#pseudo-elements

Comment: @Pete If it's just bad positioning, then why does the OP's example work as expected in other browsers? The fact that IE behaves differently than all the others (even Edge) indicates it's clearly a bug. Not that I want to belittle your solution though...

Comment: @MrLister Because other browsers are kinder in letting bad things go, ie is not, it will punish you unless you get it spot on